# Does defining a constant consume some memory?

Tags: go

I am using Go to build an application.

I need to define a lot of constants for architectural purpose. Like we have a section named `posts` and I want to perform some action on it. Its log will be saved in the system with type `posts`.

**Problem**

I have around 50 sections like this. And for ease of use of section type I wanted to define section types as constants. But Like variables consumes some space in Go, do the constants too? Should I define them like this for multi purpose or refer the type everywhere with `posts` string.

What should I follow for my requirement?

Comment: All values need to live in memory somewhere, obviously. But a handful of constants are not going to make a practical difference considering that the runtime alone takes several megabytes already. Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 5):

> Does defining a constant consume some memory?

No.

And yes. Er, sort of, but not really.

Constants are a compile-time concept in Go. That means they don't actually exist while the program is running, so in that sense, no, they don't use memory.

However, typically constants don't exist in a vacuum. They're typically *used* somewhere in your code.  For example:

```golang
const defaultName = "Unnamed"

/* then later */
var name = defaultName
```

Now the variable `name` is using memory, and it is assigned a value from the constant `defaultName`.  So the constant, itself, is not using memory, per se, but the thing referencing the constant uses memory. You could also create many (potentially thousands or more) variables that all refer to the same constant, and would thus use many times more memory.

Generally, you can imagine that every constant is replaced with its literal value.  If that literal value would "consume memory", then memory is consumed.

That is, this is equivalent to the above code snippet:

```golang
var name = "Unnamed"
```

So, the constant uses (or doesn't) the same memory that a literal value uses (or doesn't).

Comment: the example you explained above it clear, Meaning yes, constant consumes memory in indirect way. So can I use constants for my requirement ?

Comment: There are also issues with debuggers, but those are all outside the language definition: should a debugger have access to the `const` names-and-values? if so, where should they be stored?

Comment: @Amandeepkaur: If constants make sense, use them. Don't worry about memory usage.